# Can I define class methods with Module#concerning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to define class method using Module#concerning (https://github.com/37signals/concerning - part of Rails 4.1).  This would let me move modules that are used by a single class back into the class.

However, it seems that I can't define class methods.  Given this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  concerning :Programmers do
    module ClassMethods 
      def programmer?
        true
      end
    end
  end

  module Managers 
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def manager?
        true
      end
    end
  end

  include Managers
end
```

I would expect both these to work:

```
User.manager?
User.programmer?
```

But the second raises

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `programmer?' for #<Class:0x007f9641beafd0>
```

**How can I define class methods using Module#concerning?**

Comment: FWIW, sample project: https://github.com/johnnaegle/concerning-example

Comment: https://github.com/37signals/concerning/issues/1

Comment: This is fixed in Rails and concerning now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://github.com/basecamp/concerning/pull/2 fixed this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  concerning :Programmers do
    class_methods do
      def im_a_class_method
        puts "Yes!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Console:

```
> User.im_a_class_method
Yes!
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
concerning :Programmers do
  included do
    def self.programmer?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, but its not nearly as clean as I would like - the seamless module definition was really appealing.

Comment: Agreed - the feature doesn't seem completely baked yet.

Answer (score 3):

Quick workaround:

```
concerning :MeaningOfLife do
  included { extend ClassMethods }

  module ClassMethods
      ...
  end
```